# How use flag in if condition

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have a if condition for a Enum. My enum is :

```
public enum EmploymentType
{
   Type1 = 1,
   Type2 = 2,
   Type3 = 3
}
```

and this condition

```
EmploymentType type = EmploymentType.Type1 ;

if (type.HasFlag(EmploymentType.Type1 | EmploymentType.Type2 )) //if (type == (EmploymentType.Type1 | EmploymentType.Type2 ))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Expected true result for this condition, but result is false. Why?

Comment: Why not, `if (type == EmploymentType.Type1 || type == EmploymentType.Type2)`

Comment: Please, read this: [Enum Flags Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you are doing wrong here:

- Your enumeration does not have the `[Flags]` attribute. HasFlags is designed to work only with enumerations with this attribute set.
- You don't follow the flag conventions. Unless `Type3` is a combination of `Type1` and `Type2`, it should have value `4` instead of `3`. Read up on the documentation in the [FlagsAttribute MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).
- Your expectations are wrong: `HasFlag(Flag1 | Flag2)` returns only true of *both* Flag1 and Flag2 are set, since you are bitwise *OR*-ing Flag1 and Flag2 and checking if these bits are set. Please have a look at the [HasFlag documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) for details.

I suspect that your enum is meant to be *just an enum* and not a container for flags. Flags are supposed to be combinable, i.e., type could be "Type1 and Type2" or "no type" or "all types" (like font formatting, which can be "none", "bold", "italic" as well as "bold and italic", "bold and underlined", etc.). I don't think that applies to your case.

So, forget about the flags thing and just use regular enum matching (such as `type == EmploymentType.Type1 || type == EmploymentType.Type2` or a `switch` statement) instead of the `HasFlags` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your enumeration does not have the `[Flags]` attribute.

Also change your if statement to

```
if (type.HasFlag(EmploymentType.Type1) || type.HasFlag(EmploymentType.Type2))
```

Comment: The enumeration values aren't powers of two, so treating them as flags won't work.

Comment: Seemed weird to me that he was using flags in general (in the if statement), didn't notice that the third value in the enum was actually not 4...

Answer (score 1):

When you use [Flags] the enum value must be in Base 2 (Binary)

```
    [Flags]
    enum Days2
    {
        None = 0x0,
        Sunday = 0x1,
        Monday = 0x2,
        Tuesday = 0x4,
        Wednesday = 0x8,
        Thursday = 0x10,
        Friday = 0x20,
        Saturday = 0x40
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Pet {
       None = 0,
       Dog = 1,
       Cat = 2,
       Bird = 4,
       Rabbit = 8,
       Other = 16
    }
```

Comment: Would love to see a DogBirdRabbit ;)

Answer (score 0):

`|` does not mean what you think it does, and is probably best left unexplained right now. What matters is that to test "if a or b", you can use `if (a || b)`:

```
if (type == EmploymentType.Type1 || type == EmploymentType.Type2)
{
    ...
}
```